# How to use lambda capture with lock?

Tags: c++11

In the code below, the member variable (match_room_list_) is a shared resource. So I used a mutex.

But locking confuses me.

Should I use lock or not in an inner lambda function?

```
void room::join_room(int user_id) 
{
   std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
   std::shared_ptr<match_room> find_room = nullptr;

   for (auto iter : match_room_list_)
   {
      if (false == iter.second->is_public_room())
      {
            continue;
      }

      if (true == iter.second->is_full())
      {
            continue;
      }

      find_room = iter.second;
      break;
   }

   // Something

   // async ( other thread call this lambda function )
   // call database
   database_manager::get_instance().join_room(find_room->get_room_id(), user_id, [=](bool success, std::string room_id, std::vector<int> user_id_list)
   {  
      // How do you think I should using lock? 
      // std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);

      // shared resource
      match_room_list_[room_id].join_user(user_id); 

      response_join_room_ntf(room_id, user_id_list);
   }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to pass lambda to `database_manager::join_room` function ?

Comment: If the lambda is being run in a different thread then you certainly do need to lock the mutex in the lambda.  It's no different to any other function

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda function will ever run on a different thread (and that's likely) then yes, you do need to lock it.

The only possible problem with doing so could be if it was called on the same thread from a function that had already locked the mutex. But that won't be an issue here since your mutex is a *recursive* one and a given thread can lock that as many times as it wants.

---

You may also want to look into conditions such as:

```cpp
if (false == iter.second->is_public_room())
if (true == iter.second->is_full())
```

They would be far better written as:

```cpp
if (! iter.second->is_public_room())
if (iter.second->is_full())
```